# Can EC2 instances in different regions communicate over their private IP addresses?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I have two EC2 instances from an Ubuntu image, they are located in different regions. 
I just want to ask, whether they can communicate over the private IP addresses?

I have opened the required ports with a security group. I use [netcat](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/nc_openbsd.1.html) to test the communication, but it only works, when I use the public IP addresses.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It is not possible to communicate between [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) regions via the private IP addresses (except if you setup a VPN and respective routing for this, see section *VPN Solution* below), traffic between regions is in fact passing the public internet and is not distinguishable from any other internet traffic, see e.g. the following FAQs from the [Region and Availability Zone FAQ](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/FAQ_Regions_Availability_Zones.html):

- Can instances use group-based firewall rules across Regions? - *No. Group-based firewall rules only work within a Region. If you need instances to communicate with each other across Regions, you should use CIDR based firewall rules. [...]*
- What is the cost for data transfer between Regions? - *Data transferred from one Region to another is charged at both sides at the Internet data transfer rate.*

This applies to an [Amazon VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) as well, see e.g. the FAQ [Can Amazon EC2 instances within a VPC in one region communicate with Amazon EC2 instances within a VPC in another region?](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/faqs/#S8):

> Yes, **as long as all communication takes place over the Internet
>   Gateway of each VPC and uses the Elastic IP addresses** assigned to the
>   instances in each VPC. Please note: **security groups cannot span
>   regions**. All traffic filtering between instances in one VPC and
>   instances in another VPC must use the Elastic IP addresses as the
>   specified source or destination address. *[emphasis mine]*

### VPN Solution

AWS has meanwhile released two walkthroughs describing a solution for *Connecting Multiple VPCs with EC2 Instances* based on either [IPsec](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPsec) or [OpenVPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN):

- [Connecting Multiple VPCs with EC2 Instances (IPSec)](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5472675506466066)

  - please note that this tutorial facilitates [Openswan](https://www.openswan.org/), but you can achieve the same with [strongSwan](http://www.strongswan.org/) (or even the Linux IPsec stack built in as of kernel 2.6+, see e.g. [IPsec L2TP VPN server](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/IPsec_L2TP_VPN_server))
- [Connecting Multiple VPCs with EC2 Instances (SSL)](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/0639686206802544)

Answer (score 3):

Now you can do it with AWS VPC peer connection.

It enables the resources in two VPCs that are in different regions, even in different accounts, to be able to communicate with the private IP address, just like in the same LAN.

One thing you need to know is the CIDR blocks you choose for your both VPCs, they must not be in conflict. Otherwise, the peer connection can't be made successfully.

See the official doc about [VPC peer connection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html).