# Connect ec2 instances in different sites

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have set 3 hosts in EC2 in different sites [1] that should connect to an rabbitmq-server instance. I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891419/can-ec2-instances-in-different-regions-communicate-over-their-private-ip-address), but I am still a little bit confused.

Right now, the hosts only have a private IP and the public IP that is used to access the instance. I have authorized the traffic to access the rabbitmq using the `security groups`. I want to connect `HostB` and `HostC` to `HostA`. Should I have an `elastic IP` for all hosts, or do I need a VPC?

[1]: Hosts that I have set

```
HostA in Oregon and it has rabbitmq-server running.
HostB in Oregon with my application that connects to rabbitmq-server
HostC in California with my application that connects to rabbitmq-server
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options

1) run the rabbitmq in oregon so it listens on the elastic IP.  Use that address in the other servers to send traffic

<s>2) set up peering so that the VPC in the different regions can talk to each other http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-peering.html</s>

option 1 is simpler but will need careful attention to the security
<s>option 2 is more complicated but means that any other services (part from rabbitmq) across the regions will be easier/work better</s>

option 2a) is using a combination of VPC and VPN as outlined here.  http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5472675506466066

Comment: I'm pretty sure VPC Peering only works within a single region.