# AWS - how to connect two EC2 instances in two different regions?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, networking, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I'm using AWS EC2 (no other AWS services yet), and I have this setup:

```
Region 1 (N. Virginia): instance A, in VPC YYY, has public IP 123
Region 2 (S. Paulo   ): instance B, in VPC ZZZ, has public IP 456
```

I need to make a TCP request from instance B to instance A.

At first, I thought I would only need to add instance B's public IP (456) to the security group of instance A, but that didn't work (I could't establish a TCP connection as I expected).

I'm guessing that, between regions, another IP different from de public one is used when one instance tries to reach another, but not the private one since the private IP is local to the VPC (right?).

So, how to achieve this? What IP should I whitelist in the security group/firewall of instance A?

Or perhaps, in general, what's the best practice to do this? (connect two instances of different Regions/VPC between them).

Thanks!

Comment: You answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891419/can-ec2-instances-in-different-regions-communicate-over-their-private-ip-address hope it helps :-)

Comment: What does `but that didn't work` mean? If your instances are in the public subnet of the VPC and have public IPs, they should be able to communicate without a VPN. What is not working? How do you know it is not working?

Comment: @helloV I meant I couldnt establish a TCP connection from B to A. I tested this using telnet. Then, I tested it connecting to A from my local machine (added my public IP to the security group to do so) and it established the connection OK. That's why I'm asking which IP is B using when it tries to connect to A.

Comment: @helloV also, what do you mean by "public subnet of the VPC". Can subnets be public or private? I thought that regardless of subnets, all it took for an instance to be reachable was to have a public IP.

Comment: @HussainK thanks! I'll look into it. It mentions the public traffic of the subnet must be directed through the vpc gateway. Does it not do that by default? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing your VPC configuration, it is very difficult to comment. Most likely your instance B is in a private subnet of your VPC. Assuming you are running Linux, can you ping `www.google.com` from B? If you can, then `curl www.whatsmyip.com` will give you the public address of B (search for the IP in `curl` output). Use that IP to open the security group of A to allow traffic from B.

Comment: Your answer helped me realize that I had a second firewall running in the instance (ubuntu ufw), and it was that second fiewall the one that was blocking my TCP connection.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can have your ec2 instances in different regions communicate over private ip address setting up an inter-region VPC peering.

As noted in the official AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/peering/what-is-vpc-peering.html):

> You can establish peering relationships between VPCs across different AWS Regions (also called inter-Region VPC peering). This allows VPC resources including EC2 instances, Amazon RDS databases and Lambda functions that run in different AWS Regions **to communicate with each other using private IP addresses,** without requiring gateways, VPN connections, or separate network appliances.
> **The traffic remains in the private IP space**. All inter-region traffic is encrypted with no single point of failure, or bandwidth bottleneck. Traffic always stays on the global AWS backbone, and never traverses the public internet, which reduces threats, such as common exploits, and DDoS attacks. Inter-Region VPC Peering provides a simple and cost-effective way to share resources between regions or replicate data for geographic redundancy.